# anyway to avoid to loop monitor multi handle in libcurl?

Tags: c, linux, libcurl

I've read some examples from the libcurl homepage. It always uses **loop monitoring** the multi handle when download through curl_multi_perform like below:

```
curl_multi_add_handle(multi_handle, easy_handle);
do {
    curl_multi_wait(…);
    curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);
} while (still_running);
```

that make me **block** on the section of program

I want the libcurl will do callback after the anyone of easy_handle is download finished

for example:

- Server can receive requests and parse the requests to multi_handle to
  download asynchronously.
- Server still can receive requests while multi_handle is downloading.
  Those are independent(asynchronous in other words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically **curl_multi_perform** is called in a loop to complete all the curl related task, like http transaction.

The way you have put the code, you would not achieve the asynchronous way of using libcurl. There are ways to achieve it.

In a typical implementation you will have your main loop, where you might be dealing with number of task. For example

```
do
{
    execute task1
    execute task2
    .............
    execute taskn
}
while(condition)
```

In that loop, you can call **curl_multi_perform**.

So main loop looks like

```
do
{
    execute task1
    execute task2
    .............
    execute taskn

    curl_multi_perform(curlm, &count);
}
while(condition)
```

That way you will do all your task and curl_multi_perform is called time to time and you will achieve asynchronous way of using libcurl.

Please check documentation, depending on some return value you may avoid calling curl_multi_perform (I remember reading it previously).

Comment: Is ok to do `msg = curl_multi_info_read(multi, left)` after curl_multi_perform?
all examples do `curl_multi_info_read` after the `do..while` finished. That is blocking for me because I want to know whether download finished yet

Comment: Typically you call curl_multi_perform(curlm, &count) time to time. When count is greater than 0, no need to call curl_multi_info_read because by that time still certain tasks are pending. Once you find count 0, then you can call curl_multi_info_read.

Comment: did it help you ?

Comment: not at all. I saw this procedure in almost of libcurl examples. I want to know which handle finished as soon as possible. maybe it's a out of typical usage?

Comment: @code_worker - possible to know which curl handle finished job.  You call curl_multi_perform(curlm, &count) in a loop. Say you get count as 2 (you have associated 2 curl handle). At some point, count will come as 1 (change in value), that time you can call  curl_multi_info_read, it will return CURLMSG, check if resp code is CURLMSG_DONE, if so get curl handle from CURLMSG. That's the curl handle that finished the job.

Comment: yes, I understood. BTW do I must loop execute curl_multi_perform? any reason? – @Kamal

Comment: Yes, you need to call  curl_multi_perform time to time so that the tasks initiated are completed.